# Curve fitting - Excel solver

Tags: curves

I need some advise on curve fitting:

I have a 3 input function `f(x,y,z)`. The function value should be **non-negative**.

I have some raw data from experiments (both input and output) based on which I'm trying to use Excel solver to find some coefficients of 2 order function of following format  `f(x,y,z)= (ax+by+cz)^2 +dx+ey+fz`.

For the specific values of the experiment, the function is fine with the fitted data. However for data which is not as same as in experiments, I can receive **negative** values of the function.

Can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: You have most likely done an overfitting of your data due to which you are getting a good model with the training data used to build you model but weird results with test data not used to build the model. Read about overfitting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: I don't think that I've did overfitting as the sum of square errors is pretty high: 1.3, 4.5 (for 18 training points)